# Encrypting a file using openssl with a password in C

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography, openssl, des

Iam having a text file. I need to encrypt that file with a password.
In command line (-k for password and -nosalt -des3) are being used.
Is there any sample to achieve the same in C API.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need sample C code for encrypting and decrypting files using openssl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654932/need-sample-c-code-for-encrypting-and-decrypting-files-using-openssl)

Answer (score 0):

Openssl contains lots of routines for many different crypto systems, including DES.  The function you want is probably DES_ncbc_encrypt or one of the other variants, all of which are described on the des(3) man page.

Answer (score -3):

If you are on a Linux System, you can use the **crypt** function. His prototype is :

```
#include <unistd.h> 
char * crypt(const char *key, const char *salt);
```

Here is his desription (man 3 crypt) :

> The crypt() function performs password
>   encryption, based on the NBS Data
>   Encryption Standard (DES).  Additional
>   code has been added to deter key
>   search attempts.  The first
>        argument to crypt() is a null-terminated string, typically a
>   user's typed password.  The second is
>   in one of two forms: if it begins with
>   an underscore (``_''), an extended
>        format is used in interpreting both the key and the salt value, as
>   outlined below.

Comment: The crypt function truncates passwords, only uses DES1 and outputs in a base64-like format, so that may not be what the poster wanted.

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood the question. I did not see the tag openssl. Should i delete my answer?